# CSS vertical scrollbar that I want to be placed to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical crollbar that i want to sit to the right of a work page of my site, but can't seem to see how it can be moved, would love some help with this.

Here is the HTML

```
   <div class="heading">

   <h1>PRINT</h1>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-6">
  <div class="force-overflow">
  </div>
   </div>

   </div>

   <p>&nbsp;</p>



   <div class="blog-container">

<div class="work_thumbs">
  <li class="print">
    <div><a href="Work/Tree Top News/treetopnews.html"><img src="../Images/Tree Top News/Thumbs/TTN2.jpg" alt="Tree Top" border="0" class="thumb">TREE TOP NEWS</a></div>
  </li>

      <li class="print">
    <div><a href="Work/Harrow Council/harrowcouncil.html"><img src="../Images/Harrow Council/Thumbs/Harrow Logo.jpg" alt="Harrow Council" border="0" class="thumb">HARROW COUNCIL</a></div>
  </li>

      <li class="print">
    <div><a href="Work/Regent Care/regentcare.html"><img src="../Images/Regent/Thumbs/Regent logo.jpg" alt="Regent Care" border="0" class="thumb">REGENT CARE SERVICES</a></div>
  </li>

      <li class="print">
    <div><a href="Work/NLCS/nlcs.html"><img src="../Images/NLCS/Thumbs/NLCS Logo2.jpg" alt="NLCS" border="0" class="thumb">NLCS</a></div>
  </li>

     <li class="print">
    <div><a href="Work/Aish/aish.html"><img src="../Images/Aish/Thumbs/AHC.jpg" alt="Aish" border="0" class="thumb"> AISH</a></div>
  </li>

     <li class="print">
    <div><a href="Work/Dental Perfection/dentalperfection.html"><img src="../Images/Dental/Thumbs/Dental Perfection Logo.jpg" alt="Dental Perfection" border="0" class="thumb"> DENTAL PERFECTION</a></div>
    </li>

     <li class="print">
    <div><a href="Work/FJL/fjl.html"><img src="../Images/FJL/Thumbs/FJL Logo.jpg" alt="chicago graphic design" border="0" class="thumb">FJL</a></div>
     </li>

                  <li class="print">
    <div><a href="Work/Canons High/canonshigh.html"><img src="../Images/Canons high/Thumbs/Canons.jpg" alt="Canons high school" border="0" class="thumb">CANONS HIGH SCHOOL</a></div>
     </li>

                   <li class="print">
    <div><a href="Work/NCSY/ncsy.html"><img src="../Images/NCSY/Thumbs/NCSY cover.jpg" alt="NCSY" border="0" class="thumb">NCSY</a></div>
  </li>

                  <li class="print">
    <div><a href="Work/Graham Allcott/grahamallcott.html"><img src="../Images/Graham Allcott/Thumbs/GA.jpg" alt="NCSY" border="0" class="thumb">GRAHAM ALLCOTT</a></div>
  </li>
```

Here is the CSS

```
     #info
    {
font-size: 18px;
color: #555;
text-align: right;
margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    a{
color: #074E8C;
    }

    .scrollbar
    {
margin-left: 0px;
float: right;
height: 300px;
width: 25px;
left: 200px;
background: #F5F5F5;
overflow-y: scroll;
margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    .force-overflow
    {
min-height: 450px;
    }



    /*
     *  STYLE 6
     */

    #style-6::-webkit-scrollbar-track
    {
background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }

    #style-6::-webkit-scrollbar
    {
width: 10px;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }

    #style-6::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
    {
background-color: #F90; 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,
                                          rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%,
                                                  transparent 25%,
                                          transparent 50%,
                                          rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,
                                          rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
                                          transparent 75%,
                                          transparent)
    }

    .blog-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 700px;
  margin-top: 45px;
   background-color: #FFF;
display: table;
   content: '';
  clear: both;
     }

    .work_thumbs {
width:1000px;
margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
float: left;
    }

    .work_thumbs li {
margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
list-style-type: none;
display: block;
float: left;
display: inline;
font-family: "geogtq rg", Helvetica;
color: #FFF;
overflow: hidden;
    }

    .work_thumbs li a {
float: inherit;
display: block;
width: 230px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
font-family: "geogtq rg", Helvetica;
color: #00BDE5;
height: 180px;
border: 1px solid #02BDE5;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
font-size: 17px;
    }

    .work_thumbs li .type {
color: #01BDE6;
    }

    .work_thumbs li a:hover {
background-color: #ceeef6;
border-bottom: 1px solid #02BDE5;
text-decoration: none;
color: #007789;
font-family: "geogtq rg", Helvetica;
text-align: centre;
font-size: 17px;
    } 

    .work_thumbs li .thumb {
margin-bottom: 15px;
display: block;
    }
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Too much code, man. Post only the necessary part and may I suggest a little indentation? Or create a fiddle.

Comment: The code I've included is relevant to the question though

Comment: The scrollbar should be to the right only for the `rtl` users. Also try clean up your code a bit, it's a mess and contains lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: All the code that's there needs to be there, I'd be taking out important stuff on the site if I did that

Comment: Wheaton earth is wrong with my question that requires people to give so many bad votes, ridiculous. Less help more hinderence

Answer (score 0):

Had a quick look at your code and there were some issues with the markup:

try this - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ywz8U/)

css changed:
    .scrollbar
        {
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: right;
    height: 300px;
    left: 200px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
        }

```
    .force-overflow
    {

    }
```

Please look as html changed as well from

```
<div class="scrollbar" id="style-6">
  <div class="force-overflow">
  </div>
   </div>

   </div>
```

to

```
    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-6">
  <div class="force-overflow">
  </div>
```

Moved the two closing divs to lower down in the page
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks for that, really helpful. The only things is, my container which is now inside the 'scrollbar' div, has shifted to the left and can't see how to get it back to where it originally was?

Comment: Please can you put it jsfiddle and also provide some screenshot of what it should look like

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MdHz6/ and here is the screenshot http://user48140.vs.easily.co.uk/screenshot.html

Comment: If you change .scrollbar from float: right to float: left; should solve it